# WPF ListBox Template/Style (ScrollBar and InnerShadow)

Tags: wpf, templates, scrollbar, styles

Hy.

Could you help me create the fallowing control style/template?
[image]

What do I need:

1. A (Vertical and Horizontal) ScollBar Style like that. (Without the two arrow button)
2. Inner shadow on the top and bottom of the "ScrollViewer area".

   That's all I need, I can create the rest parts of the control. (Selected Item's color etc)
   Thank you.

Comment: I know this is bit old question, but did You manage to create that scrollbar template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollbar control in WPF can be thought of as collection of the two repeatbuttons and the track part. You can change the template of the scrollbar and remove the repeatbutton.

For the shadow part, you need to provide the the Zorder index. Refer to the following link - [WPF shadow on stackpanel controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571832/wpf-shadow-on-stackpanel-controls)

Comment: <DropShadowBitmapEffect> This API is now obsolete. The non-obsolete alternative is DropShadowEffect

Answer (score 0):

I know is too late for an answer but Style is very easy to get if you understand basic templating. [Here](http://loboantonio.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/estilos-y-plantillas-scrollviewer/) you will find a Scrollbar that emulate the one you want, hope you like it.